# Regex match a's separated by b's

Tags: regex

I have tried for a while to match the following case, but I'm not that great with regex and hope some help will come...

I need to match the all words contain a or b, but each a need to be separated by b's so no aa in any of the words.

**Accepted words:** a, b, ba, ababbaba
**Not Accepted words:** aa, babaa

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can anyone post a "fair" solution, without lookaheads?

Comment: I have a solution up with lookaheads, but trying mostly to figure out how to do it, without em... so thg is down the right path, simply can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^a?(ba?)*$/
```

Explaination...

```
/^         # start regex and start of string
a?         # optional a
(          # start group
  b        # exactly one b
  a?       # optional a
)*         # end group, and repeat zero or more times
$/         # end regex and end of string
```

In plain English, the first character can be an `a`, or move right onto the main repeating group, which can be repeated zero or more times, and matches a `b` followed by zero or one `a`, until the end.

#### Second method

(avoid catastrophic backtracking as per comments)

```
/^a?(b|ba)*$/
```

Explained...

```
/^         # start regex and start of string
a?         # optional a
(          # start group
  b|ba     # match `b` or `ba`
)*         # end group, and repeat zero or more times
$/         # end regex and end of string
```

In plain English, first character is `a`, or move onto main repeating group, which is repeated zero or more times, and consists of either `b` or `ba`, then end the match and regex.

Comment: +1, though I dislike the `?` in `(b+a?)*` - it might lead to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Better: `/^a?(b+a)*b*$/`

Comment: or how about... `/^a?(b|ba)*$/`

Comment: When you removed the `+` after the `b` it was already OK… Not sure about `b|ba`, the doubled `b` might not be optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Use an anchored negative look ahead:

```
^(?!.*aa)[ab]+$
```

The expression `[ab]+` means the string is composed of a's and b's (pretty straightforward).

The expression `(?!.*aa)`, anchored to the start with `^`, asserts that "aa" does not appear anywhere in the input.

---

To solve it without a look ahead:

```
^(b|ab|a$)+$
```

Terms `or`ed together are consumed in left to right preference. With that in mind, it should be obvious how the regex works.

See this regex working in a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/sxLgLqaZtO)

Comment: You might want to add `$`.

Comment: @thg435 yeah, good idea. Done.

Comment: It's close to what i want, it atleast solve it for now, but letting the question be open, to see if someone can solve it without lookahead, to tonight else im closing it there

Comment: @raaba see edited answer for a look-aheadless solution.

Comment: The second expression is a real gem. Many thanks for that one!

Answer (score 2):

The ideal RE is this:

```
^a?(b+a)*b*$
```

The key is that it is a simple RE that can be matched or rejected in a single scan, with no backtracking.

Comment: Bold statement - `The ideal RE`. Is there no room for improvement? compared to: `/^a?(b|ba)*$/`, how is it more ideal?

Comment: @Billy Bold statements always help! :-D Your RE could be changed to `/^a?(ba?)*$/`. In any case, the only way at this point to pick between them is to look at the state graph of the resulting NFA and DFA, and I'd rather have a life. (Automata state graphs are one of my least favourite things, especially when they're encoded in some weird internal form.)

Answer (score 0):

check if this works for you.
\b((a?b+a?)+)\b|\b((a?b+)+)\b|\b(((b+a?)*)\b)

I didn't have time to verify every possible case.

You can use this online [Regular Expressions Online verifier](http://regexpal.com/)

Cheers